# Codename One, Change Color of MultiButton text inside code, not GUI

Tags: java, codenameone

I need to set the color of a MultiButton text using `setUnselectedStyle()`,

This is my code

```
final MultiButton mb = new MultiButton();
mb.setTextLine1("Text1");  
mb.setTextLine2("Text2"); 
mb.setUnselectedStyle(?); //what parameter goes inside here to set the color
```

I just need to change the text color, I see the function expects a parameter of type `Style`, I am not sure what to write.

Answer (score 1):

Open the theme.res file in your src/ directory and add/change the "MultiLine1" Style

Comment: I dont want to do it in the theme res, i want to do it dynamically though code, Why: The MultiButton will have "active" and "unactive" buttons with different colors, I am creating the MultiButton inside a for loop

Comment: You can create a style "Active" and a style "UnActive" and in code do m.setUIIDLine1("Active") or m.setUIIDLine1("UnActive")

Comment: I am very new into cn1, how do i create the style and call it in my code.

Comment: Check out this section of the developer guide: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html it walks you thru it step by step

Comment: Thank you Shai, i see it now it is just like creating CSS class